# Python Google AppEngine guestbook app only partially displayed except on localhost:8080

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I followed the tutorial on https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/introduction (up to and including step 8). All runs well except that the app is displayed only partially (login feature doesn't show, no layout) when I view the uploaded version (guestbookruud.appspot.com) or the local version using the Browse button of the Google App Engine Launcher (showing port 13080). Only if I view the app locally through port 8080 all shows as intended.

What is wrong and how to solve?

Question update:
Browse button from the Launcher now gives a HTTP500 error. Here's the log (local):

```
2014-06-05 22:55:33 Running command: "['C:\\Python27\\python.exe', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\google_appengine\\dev_appserver.py', '--skip_sdk_update_check=yes', '--port=13080', '--admin_port=8005', 'C:\\Users\\ruudn_000\\Documents\\guestbook']"
INFO     2014-06-05 22:55:36,329 devappserver2.py:706] Skipping SDK update check.
WARNING  2014-06-05 22:55:36,351 api_server.py:378] Could not initialize images API; you are likely missing the Python "PIL" module.
INFO     2014-06-05 22:55:36,375 api_server.py:171] Starting API server at: http://localhost:49346
INFO     2014-06-05 22:55:36,384 dispatcher.py:182] Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:13080
INFO     2014-06-05 22:55:36,390 admin_server.py:117] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8005
OperationalError('database is locked',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\cherrypy\cherrypy\wsgiserver\wsgiserver2.py", line 1302, in communicate
    req.respond()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\cherrypy\cherrypy\wsgiserver\wsgiserver2.py", line 831, in respond
    self.server.gateway(self).respond()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\cherrypy\cherrypy\wsgiserver\wsgiserver2.py", line 2115, in respond
    response = self.req.server.wsgi_app(self.env, self.start_response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\wsgi_server.py", line 266, in __call__
    return app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\module.py", line 1407, in __call__
    return self._handle_request(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\module.py", line 621, in _handle_request
    module=self._module_configuration.module_name)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\apiproxy_stub.py", line 165, in WrappedMethod
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\logservice\logservice_stub.py", line 172, in start_request
    host, start_time, method, resource, http_version, module))
OperationalError: database is locked
OperationalError('database is locked',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\cherrypy\cherrypy\wsgiserver\wsgiserver2.py", line 1302, in communicate
    req.respond()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\cherrypy\cherrypy\wsgiserver\wsgiserver2.py", line 831, in respond
    self.server.gateway(self).respond()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\cherrypy\cherrypy\wsgiserver\wsgiserver2.py", line 2115, in respond
    response = self.req.server.wsgi_app(self.env, self.start_response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\wsgi_server.py", line 266, in __call__
    return app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\module.py", line 1407, in __call__
    return self._handle_request(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\module.py", line 621, in _handle_request
    module=self._module_configuration.module_name)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\apiproxy_stub.py", line 165, in WrappedMethod
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\logservice\logservice_stub.py", line 172, in start_request
    host, start_time, method, resource, http_version, module))
OperationalError: database is locked
```

Comment: Is that 13080 the admin Port, or the Port?  Perhaps 13080 is Admin, and the proper port is 8080?  Much more info needed.

Comment: 8005 is admin port, 13080 is port, both as displayed in the Launcher in the line of this app. App is displayed correctly using localhost:8080 however.

Comment: What do the logs say? Check the 'Logs' page from the admin console.

Comment: The logs show no errors, just 404 188 responsecodes for favicon respons messages and 200 291 response messages for the rest. Initially there was an index error in the log; that was however quickly resolved    by running a local request and then uploading again.

Comment: I'm running the latest development sdk 1.9.6. I'd be glad to provide more information it's just that I don't have a clue as to what is relevant. As far as the source code is concerned, I followed the steps as provided exactly, copying the code. To begin with I installed an update of the development SDK (from version 1.9.2). I type dev_appserver.py guestbook/ to start the local server, running "default" on port 8080, no errormessages. Further apart from not showing the full content of the webpage, no error messages whatsoever appear.

Comment: If you are using App Engine Launcher, why not hit "Run" there, where you know what port is specified?  And, turn on its Logs, so you can see what it is doing.

Comment: I did that, see log included in the question text. However I don't find a clue there to find a solution for my problem that the page is only fully displayed when accessed through port 8080? Do you find a clue or know where I should look?

Comment: Found it, I was working in a different project directory than the one I was uploading from; though ratjher stupid this explains what was going on... therefore downvote seem inappropriate?

Comment: I think this answer is relevant for you:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40679959/8244338

Answer (score 0):

Found it, I was working in a different project directory than the one I was uploading from; though rather stupid this explains what was going on...