# Running multiple services using dev_appserver.py on different ports

Tags: python, google-app-engine, dev-appserver-2

I have an application which has rest end point and web end point.

I want to run both REST and WEB service locally using dev_appserver.py

I have tried the following

`dev_appserver.py rest_app.yaml --port=5010 --admin_port=8000`

`dev_appserver.py web_app.yaml --port=5011 --admin_port=8001`

I see the following error on one of my services (rest service)

```
`OperationalError: database is locked`
```

Do I have to do anything special to make sure both those services can read/write to a shared database without any conditions (or similar bad things !!)

My goal is to run multiple services (rest and web in this case) locally and those services should data. What is the best way to do this (using dev_appserver.py locally) and in GAE itself (this will come later when I push my application to GAE :D )

Comment: Why are you treating these as separate projects though? Why not the same service with different paths?

Answer (score 14):

The reason for which you're getting `OperationalError: database is locked` is that the 2 `dev_appserver.py` instances will collide trying to access the same database local storage dir, which by default is determined based on the app's name - identical for 2 services of the same app.

One way to avoid such collision is to also specify the local storage directory, using  `dev_appserver.py`'s `--storage_path` optional argument (which you can see via `dev_appserver.py --help`):

```
--storage_path PATH   path to the data (datastore, blobstore, etc.)
                      associated with the application. (default: None)
```

However using 2 different storage paths may produce unexpected results - if your services reference what should be the same information in that storage they might see different values.

The proper way of using `dev_appserver.py` with multiple services of the same app is to run all the services through a single `dev_appserver.py` instance, which will allocate different ports to each service.

For example I have an app with 3 services and using a dispatch file. This is how I invoke the dev server, from the app dir which is the parent dir of 3 service dirs (the dispatch file must be the 1st one in the list of `.yaml` file args and I always follow it with the default module's one, in my case `main/main.yaml`):

```
/usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/local/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py --host 0.0.0.0 --log_level=debug dispatch.yaml main/main.yaml buildin/buildin.yaml apartci/apartci.yaml
```

And this is how the devserver automatically assigns the ports each service listens to, displayed when the server starts:

```
INFO     2016-11-18 14:20:53,329 api_server.py:205] Starting API server at: http://localhost:40310
INFO     2016-11-18 14:20:53,330 dispatcher.py:185] Starting dispatcher running at: http://0.0.0.0:8080
INFO     2016-11-18 14:20:53,345 dispatcher.py:197] Starting module "default" running at: http://0.0.0.0:8081
INFO     2016-11-18 14:20:53,353 dispatcher.py:197] Starting module "buildin" running at: http://0.0.0.0:8082
INFO     2016-11-18 14:20:53,361 dispatcher.py:197] Starting module "apartci" running at: http://0.0.0.0:8083
INFO     2016-11-18 14:20:53,362 admin_server.py:116] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
```

Comment: --storage_path helped me when running two different projects in dev environment. however it seems logs from one app appear in the other?

Comment: They're not different apps, they're different services of the same app. Or at least that's what this approach consider them. And yes, the devserver shows the logs together, on the real GAE infra they can be filtered by service.